# react materialize modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, materialize

react materialize library doesn't allow me to close modals. Comes with error modal is not a function. the  library uses [react-materialize](https://react-materialize.github.io/#/modals) JQuery which is sorta unuseful.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavBarStyle from   './NavBar.css';
import $ from 'jquery'; 
import   './projects.css';
import {Button,NavItem,Dropdown,Navbar,Collection,CollectionItem,Modal, 
Input,Row} from 'react-materialize'
import SideNavBar from './SideNavBar';
class AddProjectForm extends Component{
addProject = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modal').modal('close');
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <Modal  id="modal" header='Add project' 
         ref={(el) => this.modal = el}
            actions={this.submitButton}
            trigger={<a href="#" className="btn grey darken-1 white-text">Add project</a>}
            >
<form action="#" onSubmit={this.addProject}>
 <button ref={(el) => this.submitButton = el}  type="submit" className="col btn s6-offset">Add</button>
                </form>
        </Modal>
      </div>
 }
```

Comment: Did you `npm i react-materialize`?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I also added the libraries to the index.html file

Answer (score 0):

Might be a workaround:

Try triggering a click event for the hidden "modal-close" class button (I mean hide it)

```
"$('.modal-close').trigger('click')"
```

Comment: Could you please tell how you addressed the issue? if you don't mind answering.

Comment: I just made the submit button function of the modal like the code bellow `code` addProject = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addProject(this.project);
        $('.modal-close').trigger('click');
    }

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but could help someone else.
Did you try adding this to the button

```
modal="close"
```